# Boot Receiver Not Working in Oreo

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I've been reading answers for about an hour, but can't see what I'm doing wrong that is stopping my Boot Receiver from firing.

This is in my Manifest -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<receiver
            android:name=".BootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="500">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

And my BootReceiver looks like this -

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "BootReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.i(TAG ,"onReceive");

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            Log.i(TAG ,"onReceive2");
            new MainActivity().nextNotification(context);
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I can see, this should be all I need?  What could I be missing?

I'm reasonably sure it was working previously (maybe on Android N) but it's not firing now (Android O).

Is there anything I could have missed? It doesn't work on the emulator, or on my Pixel. In fact, it works fine on the emulator on API 21. I thought Boot Receiver was white listed on Oreo?

Comment: Um, `new MainActivity` looks positively frightening.

Comment: How else to I call a method from the app on boot...  so before the app has been opened?  I am new to Android programming, so happy to learn if there's a different/better way I should do it.

Comment: **Never** create an instance of an activity yourself. Only the framework can create an instance correctly, one that is properly initialized. Either move that code directly into your `BroadcastReceiver` or perhaps make it a `static` method.

Comment: I guess I could move that code into the receiver, shouldn't cause any problems. Thanks.  So, any ideas why it's not firing in Oreo?

Comment: Have you run an activity yet in that app on these devices? Manifest registered receivers do not work until something uses an explicit `Intent` to start a component, and the typical way to do that is to have the user tap on a launcher icon for the app.

Comment: Yes, so I install and run the app, reboot the device and monitor the logcat to see if 'onReceive' appears.  On Android 6 it does, on Android 8 it doesn't.

Comment: FWIW, I just tried [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.7/Intents/OnBoot) on a Nexus 5X running Android 8.0, and it worked fine, logging "Hi, Mom!" after a reboot.

Comment: Interesting. Is there anything I could be doing elsewhere in the code that would stop this from working then? Other receivers in the Manifest?

Comment: Nothing leaps to mind. See what differs between your app and mine. For example, this sample app still has `targetSdkVersion` 25; if yours has 26, try dropping to 25 and see if there's a change in your results.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Well that's odd.  I've not changed the code and it's started working again...  I have closed AS down and opened it again, so I guess there was a bug with the emulator.  I really appreciate your help, sorry to have wasted your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes Android Studio can bug out. (v3.0 Beta 4 here)  Close it all the way down and restart it and that worked for me.